# What is the model name of this two-stroke carburator?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, carburetor

There is a two-stroke engine carburetor that is found in many two-stroke engines made between 2000 and 2015. For example, you find it in hedge trimmers, weed wackers, chain saws, etc. Who makes this carburetor and what is its model number or series?

[image]

**I found out the answer to this question. If the question gets reopened, I will post the answer.**

Comment: There isn't a single carburetor put in yard equipment.

Comment: @TigerGuy I am asking about the particular carburetor shown in the picture.

Comment: @TigerGuy Are you sure. My understanding is that pretty much all gas lawn equipment has a carburetor. How else do you get the proper fuel/air mixture into the engine? If they don't exist, why does Briggs and Stratton have instructions on how to repair them? https://www.briggsandstratton.com/na/en_us/support/maintenance-how-to/browse/carburetor-repair-maintenance-how-to-guide.html

Comment: @EricShain, sure they have carburetors, but every manufacturer tends to design and manufacture their own.

Comment: @TigerGuy I misinterpreted your comment. Sorry.